# How to sync two monitors and a projector together to display the same game while controlling the recording it from one of the two computer monitors?

Tags: windows-7, video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I want to display MK9 on a projector and a computer monitor on which the game will be played by two people and record it from a second monitor. All devices will be hooked up to the administrative computer and the recordings will be controlled via this computer. Video of game should be shown without delay (game is MK9 on PS3).

The projector will be used to display the game to a group of people, while one of the monitors will be used for the gamers to play the game.  And the last monitor is for the administrator to control the recordings of the action.

In otherwords, I'd like to clone only two monitors and make the third individual

Can I implement this, if I already have AVerMedia Game Broadcaster HD, Sapphire Radeon HD7850, Intel Core i7-2600K and sufficient ports and adapters for this. OS Win 7 x64

Comment: Are you asking if your graphic card supports 3 outputs?

Comment: No. My card support 4 outputs. I asking - how to clone only two monitors and make a third individual?

Comment: I've updated your question +1 as it's a great and clear question. Hopefully you'll get an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Program called Actual Multiple Monitors: http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/

And a Freeware-Tool, I just have found: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortool/

You can change what is displayed on a monitor and also when you are in Fullscreen, you can lock the mouse to prevent the game from minimizing or you can stretch the game over 2+ Screens.

Hope I could Help.

Regards, m0ddixx